# Raising OnPropertyChanged in the setter of each property vs Instance of Object

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged

**Information for the question:**

I am trying to understand how to properly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on objects and collections.

First, here is my ViewModelBase class:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertychanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Consider that I have a class called `Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

To use `INotifyPropertyChanged`, most examples that I have seen change the Person class to something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertychanged();
        }
    }

    private string _age;
    public string Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            OnPropertychanged();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work exactly the same when used a single time on an instance of the object (This might be useful if there are a lot of properties):

```
private Person _person;
public Person MyPerson
{
    get { return _person; }
    set
    {
        _person = value;
        OnPropertychanged();
    }
}
```

**Actual question:**

1 - Does it make a difference (aside from amounts of code) whether you call `OnPropertychanged()` on each individual property verses on an instance of an object? (Are both considered good practice?)

2 - If setting `OnPropertychanged()` on the object instance is good practice, am I correct to create an `ObservableCollection` like this?:

```
var PersonCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyPerson>();
```

Comment: Where you put your "PropertyChanged" method it really up to you on how fine grain of updates to the UI do you want. Meaning... if you want all fields to be updated (on UI) as the are changed in the model then they need to call the "PropertyChanged" method to push changes to the UI.

Comment: @Edd I'm testing different scenarios. I am only able to bind to properties (or objects) that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the viewmodel. If `Person` is in its own class (and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and I do this from the ViewModel: `var person = new Person() { Name = "John", Age = 34 }` the binding doesn't work. Is that normal?

Comment: Okay, lets layout a.... You have a listbox that binds to an ObservableCollection of Person. That list will auto update as you add/remove a "Person" to the collection, but suppose that you also display the "Selected" item(Person) to the right of the list, if your "Person" implements "PropertyChanged" interface then the "Selected Item" (Person) will auto update as well. If not, then you will have to refresh the list and select the item again to get the current values. If you have some code I can help point it out better. Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

1) Well, if you want to call it on object instance, then you need to do it every time you use your class like this in binding. When you implement `OnNotifyPropertyChanged` directly inside your class, you don't need to care about it later on...

2) Classes with `INotifyPropertyChanged` do not require Observable collections. This is however must when you are binding colection do some UI control (`ListBox`, `ListView`) and want to add/remove its elements. Observable collection will then make sure the UI gets updated.

Answer (score 2):

The ObservableCollections object... When adding and removing from this collection the UI will be notified of the changes (Top Level). If you have an "ObservableCollection of Person" and you change a property on the one of the objects(Person) in the list the UI will not update unless your "Person" class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, which can be put into a base class that all classes can inherit from like your example. I hope this helps a little.